# How to create industrial automation images in GoJS and use it

Tags: gojs

[Industrial Automation images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KumDS.png)

I want to create custom industrial automation images in GoJS of any shapes like (Pump, Motor, Machine, Mixer, Valve, Tank) and used it. I want to use in below sample.

https://gojs.net/latest/samples/draggableLink.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen samples such as https://gojs.net/latest/samples/processFlow.html?

GoJS does not provide the shapes that you want, but you can make your own by using the SVG definitions of such shapes that you find elsewhere or draw yourself.  Either show them using **Picture**s as if they were images, or get their geometry and use them in **Shape**s: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/icons.html